# Does all neurons in the same layer compute same result?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

Excuse my nubish question but:

Imagine I have a Neural Network with 3 Layers.
If all Neurons in the 2nd Layer compute the very same function: σ[Σ(wi*xi) + b]
Doesn't that mean that all neurons in that layer compute the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because each neuron has different weights. `w` and `b` are different for each neuron.

Comment: Ok. Are you sure b is different for each Neuron in the same layer?

Comment: You can use the same `b` if you want, but it is better to calculate a different `b` for each neuron, in order to allow the network to do more complex calculations.